# What current code coverage tools for Java can show coverage from a tests point of view?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage

There are many code coverage tools that reached the end of life which makes looking up tools a bit difficult. I'm wondering if anyone has experience with a tool that can show code coverage from a test point of view for Maven projects in Java.

Something like this:

```
Test: myTest 
Coverage:covers 30 % of source code.
```

and export this result in either XML or JSON.

**Example with Jacoco.** From information written by @cesarsotovalero

Run one test method with

```
mvn clean verify -Dtest=yourTestClass#yourTestMethod
```

Or run a test class with

```
mvn clean verify -Dtest=yourTestClass
```

Or run the whole test suite with

```
mvn clean test
```

The name of the test/s will now exist in `\target\surefire-reports\TEST-yourTest.xml`
The coverage results will be in `\target\site\jacoco\jacoco.xml`

Now you can read the test name/s and map it to the test result/s. At the bottom of the XML in `\target\site\jacoco\jacoco.xml` there is a summary:

```
<counter covered="10" missed="19" type="INSTRUCTION"/>

<counter covered="3" missed="5" type="LINE"/>

<counter covered="3" missed="2" type="COMPLEXITY"/>

<counter covered="3" missed="2" type="METHOD"/>

<counter covered="2" missed="0" type="CLASS"/>
```

Test coverage for the test in `\target\surefire-reports\TEST-yourTest.xml` is
3 / (3+5) = 37,5 %

Comment: What do you mean by "30 % of source code". ? Sometimes called a line coverage ? JaCoCo you could also take a look at OpenClover https://openclover.org/ ...

Comment: I want a number that tells me how much % of the code the test covers. say the source code is 10 lines. I create a test that test the first 5 than that test should have 50 % test coverage.

Answer (score 0):

[JaCoCo](https://www.jacoco.org/) does exactly what you're asking for. Add it as a plugin to the `pom.xml` file of your Maven project as follows:

```
<build>
      <plugins>
         <!-- JaCoCo plugin-->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>report</id>
                  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>report</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
```

To get the % of coverage of a single test, run:

```
mvn clean verify -Dtest=myTestClass#myTestMethod
```

The coverage results will be exported to `./target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml`. Also, a nice HTML report will be generated at `./target/site/jacoco/index.html`.

You can parse the `jacoco.xml` file to get the coverage of the test w.r.t the tested class: `(lines missing + lines covered) / lines covered`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However if I have say 100 tests. Then i would have to run this 100 times, yes? was kinda hoping for it to be a feature of the plugin
also i'm getting the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:check (default-check) on project JacocoTest: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details. -> 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: @Yanara: No, you don't need to run it 100 times. You run `mvn test` and then collect the coverage information of your 100 tests from the `jacoco.xml` file. JaCoCo collects the coverage information after executing the tests with the  [Maven surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html). Add the surefire and JaCoCo plugins to your `pom`.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm having a bit of trouble following here.

So in my jacoco.xml exist the result of the test data.
In \target\surefire-reports I can see which tests ran

Now if I run the tests 1 by 1 I can make a connection between each test and it's coverage by mapping the surefire report with the jacoco.xml

But I dont understand how i can do this without running 100 tests? 1 test for each mapping. Could you please show with an example?

Comment: To get the coverage you need to **execute** the tests, there is no other way since the coverage information is obtained dynamically. So, the only way I know is letting Maven surefire executing the tests, then JaCoCo collects the coverage information and gives you a report.

Comment: due to the limits of comments i've edited my orignal post. Is that what you mean? because if so then if I have 100 tests i would have do

mvn clean verify -Dtest=yourClass#yourTest(n) where n is 1 <= n <= 100